# Как себя ведет @Scheduled spring-аннотация в среде с несколькими нодами и балансировщиком?

Tags: java, spring

Приложение на spring+java+websphere

Есть метод, который помечен аннотацией @Scheduled и выполняется по расписанию раз в сутки(выполняет работу с бд)

Приложение развернуто на WebSphere на нескольких нодах. Они управляются балансировщиком. Я так понимаю что все ноды работают с одной бд, могут ли при этом возникнуть проблемы потому, что на нескольких нодах запустилась эта задача?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, в простом случае на каждом узле будет работать по своему планировщику. Это черевато серьёзными проблемами, включая гонку/блокировку данных. Есть множество решений. Простейшее из них, в конфигурации узлов железно сделать один из узлов ***единственным*** на котором будет работать планировщик. К примеру это можно сделать при помощи spring-профилей:

```java
@Component
@Profile("nodeWithScheduler")
public class ProdJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${job.cron}")
    public void runJob() {

    }

}
```

Далее в параметры одного из узлов добавить JVM-параметр `-Dspring.profiles.active=nodeWithScheduler`. Однако такое решение не отказоустойчивое, т.к. при выходе из строя указанного узла, данный планировщик не начнет автоматически работать на другом узле.

Если требуется отказоустойчивый кластер, то следует посмотреть в сторону таких утилит как [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com) или [Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org). Ну или в простейшем случае использовать утилиту, которая может делать кластерные блокировки через базу. К примеру [ShedLock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock) или надстройку над [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html).

---

P.S. Я решал подобную проблему при помощи [Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org) в англоязычной версии. См. [Вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780890/apache-ignite-how-to-create-timer-task-cron-based-without-it-execution-on-per). Там же есть и ответ.

Comment: А можете подсказать по поводу надстройки над Quartz - с ним вроде все понятно, но как сделать так чтобы он работал нормально в кластере, как гуглить?

Comment: @Roberto В ответе есть ссылка на [официальную документацию](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html). Тут есть [пример](https://medium.com/@Hronom/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-in-cluster-mode-457f4535104d). Тут есть [пример](https://jeroenbellen.com/configuring-a-quartz-scheduler-in-a-clustered-spring-boot-application/) попроще и поновее

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы могут возникнуть и скорее всего возникнут.

Причина в том что все ноды будут выполнять этот метод одновременно.